# Computer won't fully shut down

Tags: windows-10, ssd, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I built a gaming PC last summer and recently upgraded my processor.  Since upgrading, when I shut off my PC the OS seems to properly shut down and my displays lose signal.  However, my PC appears to stay on.  The power light remains lit and all fans are still running.  The disk light does not turn on in this state.  I am turning the PC off using the start menu.  Restarting results in the same state without the PC turning back on.  I am able to turn the PC off by holding down the power button or flipping the switch on my power supply.

It also may be worth noting that I currently have a dual monitor setup where my main HD monitor is connected to my GPU out and my secondary SD monitor is connected to my motherboard by enabled IGPU Multimonitor in my UEFI settings.

Here are my PC Specs:

- ASRock B250M Motherboard
- 8 GB RAM (Crucial)
- NVidia GeForce GTX 1060 6 GB EVGA ACX 2.0 (Single Fan)
- Intel i5 7600k (Upgraded from Intel Pentium g4650) (Stock CPU Cooler) (Not overclocked)
- Crucial MX300 2.5-inch SSD (275 GB)(Boot Drive)
- Toshiba 2 TB HDD (Secondary Storage)
- EVGA 450B Power Supply
- Windows 10 Professional

What I've already tried:

- Windows Update
- Power Troubleshooter (No Problems)
- Windows Update Troubleshooter (Fixed problems but not shut down)
- Hardware and Devices Troubleshooter (Fixed problems but not shut down)
- Patience.  I gave it about 8 hours or so (overnight) to turn off but it failed to do so
- Fixed one disk issue with Glary Utilities 5

Comment: What happens when you press Win+R keys and type *shutdown /s /t 0*  ? If that shuts the system completely, then check what the power buttons do and the power plan.

Comment: Your MB might require a BIOS update to support the new CPU

Comment: https://www.asrock.com/support/index.asp?cat=BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Have found this to be a bad cmos battery in most cases. Solved several similar issues, most recent being on a HP Elitebook folio  9470m by replacing the cmos battery. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Turn off **Fast Startup**. Some computers (and even processors) don't handle fast startup properly, and as a result, it won't shut down properly.

1. Right-click the Start button.
2. Click **Search**.
3. Type **Control Panel** and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.
4. Click **Power Options**.
5. Click **Choose what the power buttons do**.
6. Click **Change settings that are currently unavailable**.
7. Click **Turn on fast startup (recommended)** so that the checkmark *disappears*.
8. Click **Save changes.**

([source](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup))

Comment: Highly unlikely, since Fast Startup is purely a software thing. Under the hood it’s plain hibernation. Of course, *drivers* might interfere.

Comment: @DanielB Some computers don't handle hibernation properly.

Answer (score 0):

My Acer Aspire E1-771G could not completely stop(shutdown) after Shutdown or Sleep commands selected in OS. After numerous versions of Win10 installs, I opened the laptop and replaced the CMOS battery. Turns out the battery was at 2.99v and the new battery was on 3.11v which immediately solved the cannot shutdown issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ACPI is enabled in your BIOS Settings, without that, Windows cannot perform the shutdown process